# Obtener atributos del mismo div

Tags: jquery

tengo un numero x de divs por este ejemplo 2

```
<div class="vtexsc-skuQtt" data-index="0">3</div>
<div class="vtexsc-skuQtt" data-index="1">3</div>
```

con esto recorro los div y le agrego un input con botones.

```
$(".vtexsc-skuQtt").each(function(){
    Skuquanty = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<div><button class='menos' name='menos' type='button'>-</button><input name='contador' type='text' value='"+Skuquanty+"'><button class='mas' name='mas' type='button'>+</button></div>");
});
```

Con esto darle clic en "mas" se va sumar de 1 a 1 al input.

```
$("html").on("click", "button[name='mas']", function(){
    let numero = Number.parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val());
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val(numero + 1);

    //aca aprovechando el clic quiero obtener el atributo "data-index"
    $(".vtexsc-skuQtt").each(function(){
    var indexProduct = $(this).attr("data-index");
    console.log(indexProduct);
    });
});
```

pero asi me trae los 2 atributos osea "0" y "1".
como podría traer el atributo al cual se la da clic, si le doy clic donde el atributo es "0" que me traiga el 0

Gracias.

Comment: En realidad te muestra (con el `console.log`) siempre los dos porque en el `$(".vtexsc-skuQtt").each(function(){` vuelves a recorrer todos los de esa clase (que son los dos del inicio) y no aquel sobre el que se hizo click. Para eso, tienes que acceder al `.attr("data-index")` del `$(this).parent().parent()`.

Comment: De todos modos, al principio, cuando recorres `$(".vtexsc-skuQtt").each(function(){` puedes obtener también el `.attr("data-index")` y crear ese atributo también al input y botones. Es cierto que es un poco redundante, pero después facilita un acceso más directo. Pero esto ya es opcional

Comment: osea quito el each?

Comment: Exacto... quitas el `each` donde tienes el `console.log(indexProduct);` porque en realidad recorre todo y no está enlazado con el div del botón donde hiciste click. Pero también hay que hacer lo otro que hice... acceder atributo `data-index` del div correspondiente (y no de los dos div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría simplificar y o mejorar todavía más, por ejemplo con una clase común para ambos botones para programar el `on('click'...)` en la misma función, porque ya tienes tus clases `mas` y `menos` y en realidad haces exactamente lo mismo salvo por el signo (sumar o restar).

Pero sin querer cambiar mucho de tu código inicial, te pongo un ejemplo que soluciona lo que te había comentado...

```
$(".vtexsc-skuQtt").each(function(){
    Skuquanty = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(
        "<div><button class='menos' name='menos' type='button'>-</button>" +
        "<input name='contador' type='text' value='"+Skuquanty+"'>"+
        "<button class='mas' name='mas' type='button'>+</button>"+
        "</div>"
    );
});

$("html").on("click", "button[name='mas']", function(){
    let $div_abuelo = $(this).parent().parent(),
      numero = Number.parseInt($div_abuelo.find("input[name='contador']").val());
    $div_abuelo.find("input[name='contador']").val(numero + 1);
    console.log ("Cambiando valor para data-index ", $div_abuelo.attr("data-index"));
});
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: me funciono gracias!!, una consulta adicional, en el caso de que le aplique el each inicial a un div y el atributo este en un div hermano usaria el siblings?

Comment: Exacto... si quieres acceder a sus hermanos (hablo de divs hermanos), podrías hacer `$arr_hermanos = $div_abuelo.siblings();` O eligiendo uno concreto por medio de una clase, o lo que sea. No se me ocurre en qué casos te interesaría, la verdad, pero vamos... poder, sí podrías

Comment: si asi era, muchas gracias :)